# Request Mapping Configuration set globally in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I have a request mapping in every controller like below, now I want to set this configuration from one place of my applications

Here is my code:

```
@RestController(value = "AC1004Controller")
@RequestMapping(value = { "api/v1/accounting"},method = RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
public class AC1004Controller {
}
```

My target coding is, need to replace the below code from one place of our application

```
 @RequestMapping(value = { "api/v1/accounting"},method = RequestMethod.POST ,consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally you map controller's methods with GET, POST, etc ..

so below should be configuration..

1. Define a property in application.properties

   ```
   api.endpoint.accounting=/api/v1/accounting
   ```
2. Below controller should mapped with your accounting controller with different-2 methods for post, get to mapped with controller method.

   ```
   @RestController(value = "AC1004Controller")
   @RequestMapping(value = "${api.endpoint.accounting}")
   public class AC1004Controller {

       @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
       MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE})
       public ResponseEntity<?> addAccount(@RequestBody Account account) {

      }

      //for get mapping

      @GetMapping
      public ResponseEntity<?> getAccount() {

      }
   }
   ```

Comment: getting error to this line api.endpoint.accounting=api/v1/accounting

Comment: Did you define it in application.properties? Then where error is coming ??

Comment: @shohel sorry there was typo use slash in starting api.endpoint.accounting=/api/v1/accounting

Comment: I am new in spring boot, i did not understand your terms. I defined application.properties into pom.xml

Comment: ok, you should have a file application.properties under /src/main/resources where you can define properties and they can be called like I called in request mapping by ${} so define it under path I have given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `spring.mvc.servlet.path` property in `application.properties` file.
Like this:
`spring.mvc.servlet.path=/AC1004Controller`

Answer (score -1):

You just put any of these configurations on application properties file (yaml or properties).

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=/api  
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
```